# Validate presence before custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, activemodel

```
validates :place_id, :title, :level, :start_at, :end_at, :presence => true
validate :event_takes_place_in_one_day, :event_is_not_in_past

def event_takes_place_in_one_day
    binding.pry
    self.start_at.day == self.end_at
end
```

and bang! error, when start_at or end_at  is nil.

```
undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass
-
app/models/meeting.rb:22:in `cover?'
app/models/meeting.rb:22:in `event_is_not_in_past'
app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

Afaik it is also possible to implemnt this with custom validator, but I suppose this is not the case, because of there is only one validator per class, so I should do three classes for 3 checks, isn't it?

P.s.

Application have a Meeting model with start_at and end_at DateTime type 
attributes, which indicate a start and the end of the meeting 
respectively.
I need to implement next logic
start_at < end_at (that it starts after than end)
start_at.day == end_at.day (meeting ends within one day)
and also meeting can be created only for the current month.

Answer (score 1):

Will a nil check work for you?

```
def event_takes_place_in_one_day
  #only execute if start_at & end_at is not nil
  unless self.start_at.nil? || self.end_at.nil?
    binding.pry
    self.start_at.day == self.end_at 
  end
end
```